# will git clean -f affect current branch or all branches

Tags: git

I have local working branch **branchA** , **branchB** , **branchC**.

My current working branch is **branchB**. If I run `git clean -f` will it just clean the untracked files in my **branchB** or all untracked files in my other branches too?

Comment: Untracked files aren't part of a branch -- they're untracked, which means they're not managed by git and are not part of your repository. Running `git clean -f` will not affect *any* branches. It will simply remove files in your working directory that aren't managed by `git`.

Comment: @larsks i got 3 local branches. i just want clean the branchB, so the other local branches still maintain the untracked files that i clean from branchB?

Comment: I'm not sure I can be any more clear: untracked files have nothing to do with branches. A branch does not "maintain" untracked files; if a file is untracked, that means git doesn't know about it and won't manage it.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify your exact question, removing untracked files doesn't "affect" **any** branch (or commit). Instead, `git clean -f` will delete all of the untracked files **from the point of view of the currently checked out commit**.

Suppose you have two branches:

- `branch1` is tracking just one file: `file1`.
- `branch3` is tracking three files: `file1`, `file2`, and `file3`.
- For simplicity let's assume you don't have any files ignored.

Your working directory currently has 5 files: `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`, and `file5`, and you have `branch1` currently checked out.

If you run `git clean -f` in this case, all files would be deleted except for `file1`. If you had those same 5 files in your working directory but instead `branch3` was checked out, then only `file4` and `file5` would be deleted.

Note in the case where you have `branch1` checked out, the fact that you are deleting `file2` and `file3` doesn't matter. As soon as you checkout `branch3` again those 2 files will come right back.

Comment: Follow-up on the last paragraph: If, on the other hand, you have checked out `branch3` and `file4` and `file5` have been removed by `git clean`, then check out `branch1`, you do not have the clean away `file2` and `file3` because the act of switching branches removed them.

Comment: @j6t hehe. I actually started writing that exact thing in that note, and then decided against it, though barely. The fact that you mentioned it makes me kind of want to put it back...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit like asking whether airplanes tear holes in the cotton candy (or "candy floss" to the British) clouds so that bits fall down to the ground, or whether they eat the cotton candy clouds when they fly through them.  That is, there's a fundamental error, so that the question can't be answered.  Just as clouds in the sky *aren't* cotton candy in the first place, untracked files *aren't* in a branch.

Here's what you need to know:

- A *Git repository* does not store *files*, at least not directly.  It stores *commits*.  (Each *commit* then stores files, but in a peculiar Gitty fashion.)
- Branches, in the sense you're thinking of them, don't really exist.  Multiple different things *do* exist, and they are all called *branches* (by different people at different times), and it's probably not possible to use and talk about Git without saying the word *branch*.  But when someone says "branch" without enough context, you should wonder what they're talking about—and perhaps, even, whether *they know* what they're talking about.
- Hence we should strive to say *branch name* rather than *branch* for cases like this one: "I have three branch names".  Or, we should strive to say *tip commit* rather than *branch* for cases like: "branch name **branchA** locates tip commit `a123456`".
- When we do get to specific commits—whose "true names" are those big, ugly, random-looking hash IDs like `d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376`—each of those commits stores (indirectly) a *full snapshot of every file*, but the files *in* the commit are frozen for all time, so that we can get them back any time in the future by calling up that particular commit using that particular hash ID.

Once a commit is made, no part of it—neither the snapshot nor the metadata—can ever be changed by anything, not even by Git itself.  The files in the commit just aren't writable.  They're also not even *readable* by most programs; Git has special code to read them once they become packed.  (A "loose" object is just zlib-compressed, so if you have a zlib function, you can at least read it without having to use Git—but you'll need Git anyway so you might as well let Git read it for you.)

What this means is that a commit works great as an *archive*, but is utterly useless when it comes to getting any *new work* done.  The only way to get *new* work done is to *extract* some existing commit.  The extraction process—i.e., `git switch` or `git checkout`—*checks out* all the files from the snapshot, turning each Git-ified, archived file into an ordinary read/write file that ordinary computer programs on your ordinary computer can use ordinarily.  (How extraordinary is that? )

If you have ever used any *other* version control system, this general idea is actually probably pretty familiar.  For instance, old (1970s and onward) era centralized version control systems would have a central "master source" versioning system that would keep the forever-saved versions of things, and you'd call it up somehow and have it hand over copies of files so that you could do work.  When you were done doing work, you'd hand back all your updates (in some form or another) and the version control system would add them to the forever-saved versions.

This leads naturally to the idea that there are always *two* copies of each of the files you're working on:

- there's the frozen one that you got from the versioning system, and
- there's the one you're working on / with.

#### Git's index

With the above in mind, we're *almost* ready to explore `git clean`.  But not quite!  Unlike all those other version control systems, Git—for reasons known only to Linus Torvalds—stores not just *two* copies of each file, but *three*.  Two of these copies are in the internal Gitty format, where they're compressed and de-duplicated.  One is of course an ordinary file, so that you can do work.

Git refers (poorly and not very consistently) to these three copies as:

- the `HEAD` version: that's in the *current commit*, and is frozen for all time;
- the *index* or *staging* version, and
- the *working tree* version.

When you initially *check out* some commit, with `git switch` or `git checkout`, *all three versions match*.  Because the index / staging version is kept in the same *format* as the frozen version, and this format de-duplicates duplicated files, this extra "copy" takes no space at all.<sup>1</sup>  The copy in your *working tree* is an ordinary file, though, and takes whatever space it takes.  That's not really a big price to pay since you need the file to be available.<sup>2</sup>

Now, that's the state *right after* an initial clone-and-checkout.  When you first run `git clone`, Git makes an *empty* working tree: this has no files at all in it.  It then copies all the *commits* from some other Git repository to your own new local Git repository, and then creates some non-branch names to remember the other Git repository's branch names.  Last, it creates *one* branch name in *your* repository, making that name select one particular *commit* it just copied, and then *checks out* that one commit via that one name.

So now, you have those three copies of every file: the frozen `HEAD` copy, the index / staging copy, and the working-tree copy.  Your repository is "clean", whatever the word "clean" might mean.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Each "index entry" needs to use up some space to store information *about* the file, and that generally adds up to very roughly 100 bytes per file, so it's not really *no* space, it's just a tiny amount of space, regardless of how much space the file-data needs.

<sup>2</sup>Except, that is, if you *don't* need the file to be available.  What if there are hundreds of gigabytes of frozen-copy files that you don't need?  But that's for advanced Git.

<sup>3</sup>There are a couple of oddball, anomalous cases in Git, most often encountered on Windows for various reasons, where the initial clone-and-checkout *doesn't* give you a "clean" setup.  We won't touch those here.

---

#### Getting dirty

So, okay, we start out with a fresh new clone: everything is "clean".  But then we start doing work, and things get "dirty".  What does this mean?

Here are the tricks to know:

1. Your working tree, where you can work on your files, *is an ordinary set of files and folders on your computer*.  Anything you can do on your computer, you can do here.  *Git* has no control over this, and in general, no *knowledge about* you doing things as you do them.<sup>4</sup>
2. Git's *index* or *staging area*—I mentioned that Git is not very consistent about the words it uses here; it also uses the word *cache* sometimes, as in `git rm --cached`—is *not* an ordinary set of files-and-folders.  It's under Git's control.  But only particular Git commands *affect* this index / staging-area thing.
3. Git's *commits*, where the frozen-for-all-time files live, *can't be changed*.  All you can do is pick out some other commit you want to use, or add new commits.  You cannot hurt an old commit!  At worst (and this is pretty bad), you can *lose* an old commit, i.e., be unable to find its hash ID.  (If you can't *find* the commit, you can't *use* it.)

   **Caveat:** if you destroy the *repository*—the stuff in the hidden `.git` folder—*that* will destroy the saved commits, and your OS will probably let you do that, if you tell it to.

Git will call the working tree *dirty* if you *change the contents of the files*.  To know that the working tree *is* dirty, Git has to *scan the files* and compare them to something.

Because the working tree is a *folder*, you can create new files here.  If you do create a new file, it shows up—but it's not in Git's index until and unless you tell Git to copy it there.  And if it's a totally new, never-before-seen file, it's obviously not in any existing *commit* either.

When you modify your working tree files, and/or add and/or remove some of them, you've "dirtied" your working tree in various ways.  *This isn't quite what `git clean` cleans.*  Git's terminology is often very poor and misleading.  But you should know this clean/dirty terminology.

If you'd like to make a *new* commit using *updated files*, you will want to run `git add`.  What `git add file` does is simple enough: it tells Git: *Read file `file` and compress it into your internal, ready-to-commit format, and check to see if the contents are duplicated; in any case, make the new version ready to be committed.*

The index copy is now updated to match the working tree copy.  The working tree copy is obviously "less dirty" now (is it dirty at all? Git doesn't exactly say), and `git status` will tell you that you have something *staged for commit*, referring to the index's role as the "staging area".

---

<sup>4</sup>Git now includes a thing called the "file system monitor" that is an attempt to make stuff go faster.  This go-faster code *tries* to get help from your OS so that Git *can* see things as you do them in your working tree.  This can't *stop you* from doing things, and on most systems, it can *miss* things, so it doesn't really change the overall picture, except that if the file system monitoring code has bugs—it often does, as this stuff is very hard to get right—and you turn it *on* and things get weird, you might want to turn it *off* again to avoid hitting these bugs.

---

#### Untracked files

If you make an all-new file in your working tree, though, there's *no copy of this file* in Git's index.  Git puts this new file into a special category: Git calls this an *untracked file*.

The definition of *untracked file* is actually pretty simple: **An untracked file is any file that exists *right now* in your working tree, but does not exist *right now* in Git's index / staging-area.**

Obviously, then, one way to make an untracked file is to create a new file with a name that has never occurred before.  That file's name won't be in Git's index.  But there's another way to make a file untracked:

```
git rm --cached existing-file
```

This tells Git to *remove* a particular file from Git's index, *without also removing the file from the working tree*.  Why was the file in Git's index before you ran this?  *Probably*, because it was copied out of the commit.  If that's the case, the file is *still in the commit*.  Remember that we can't *change* any existing commit.  But it *might* have been in Git's index because you ran `git add`.

It doesn't really matter why it was there before.  What matters is whether it's there *now*.  If you have a file in your working tree, and don't have a file with the same name in Git's index, that file is an *untracked file*.  That's it—that's all there is to it—but there are multiple different ways to *get* that.

**These are the files that `git clean` cleans.**  The `git clean` command operates only on *untracked* files, which are files that are in your working tree, yet not in Git's index.  But there's more, because Git has one more wrinkle here.

#### "Ignored" files

We already know, from the above, that if a file is in Git's index, it is *tracked*.  A tracked file won't be removed by `git clean`.  It won't be ignored either.  All tracked files are tracked, and that's all there is to it unless you run `git rm --cached` to make them suddenly be *un*-tracked.

Untracked files, however, are split into two groups:

- Untracked files that *aren't* listed in a `.gitignore` or similar file cause `git status` to *complain*.
- Untracked files that *are* listed in a `.gitignore` or similar file *do not* cause `git status` to *complain*.

So, the `.gitignore` entries exist to stop Git from complaining—especially, to stop `git status` from complaining.  But they do more than just that:

- Listing an untracked file in `.gitignore` makes `git status` stop complaining about it.
- Listing an untracked file in `.gitignore` makes `git add` refuse to *add* it to Git's index.  (You can still add it, but you must use `--force` or `-f`.)
- And—the reason for mentioning all this here in the first place—being untracked-and-ignored vs untracked-but-not-ignored affects how `git clean` decides whether to *remove* a working tree copy of some file.

In particular, the `-x` and `-X` options to `git clean` affect whether untracked-but-also-ignored files are removed, or not.

#### Putting this all together

The bottom line is this: `git clean` removes *some or all untracked files*.  Exactly *which* untracked files depends on arguments you pass *to* `git clean`.

This, like so many other things in Git, *requires* that you understand precisely what an *untracked file* is and how `.gitignore` works with untracked files.  If your Git tutorial did not explain this whole tracked vs untracked, and untracked with or without "ignore" option, thing, that tutorial needs work.  Some people (and tutorials) try to skip over the concept of Git's index / staging-area using `git commit -a`, but this just doesn't work: you run into un-answerable things like this unless you know how the index works.

We have not covered everything about Git's index here.  In particular, when you're doing a merge operation and have *merge conflicts*, the index takes on an expanded role.  But this is what you need to know just to get started.